# vuejs return map() object contents into data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am struggling to figure out a way to return the contents of a Map() object from the countall() method to the data in order to display them dynamically in the template.

It seems as though I am limited with the Vue methods, as it is impossible to have multiple non-nested functions operate under one VueJS function in the methods.

Currently, the code I have looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-1">
  <div class="list__input" @keydown.enter="add">
  <input v-model="newBeneficiary" placeholder="Add beneficiary"  />
  <input v-model="newClass" placeholder="Add new task topic" />
  <input v-model="newItem" placeholder="Add new task text"  />
  </div>
  <div class="list__item" v-for="item in items" :key="item">
    {{ item.beneficiarytext }} {{ item.classtext }} {{ item.message }}
    {{ countall() }}
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        beneficiarytext: '',
        classtext: '',
        message: ''
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.items.unshift({beneficiarytext: this.newBeneficiary, classtext: this.newClass, message: this.newItem });
      this.newItem = '';
      console.log(this.items);
    },
    countall: function() {
        this.items.reduce((map, item) => {
          map.set(item.classtext, (map.get(item.classtext) || 0) + 1)
          return map
        }, new Map());
      }
  }
})
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling countall method on every iteration of <div class="list__item" v-for="item in items" :key="item">? Isn't enough to call it once?

Comment: I want the map to update on every addition to the data.items

Comment: But calling it inside the loop like you do, will count (and increment each time) the items for every item rendered. I think you should call it once, when you initialize the items collection. After that, you should have methods to detect when an item has been added or removed to update the map only for the corresponding classtext

Comment: do you want count your items and display them?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ideally want to do so: "itemname":itemnumber